# How to make c++ server using gSOAP?

Tags: c++, client-server, gsoap

I'm making server side which will be written in c++ using gSOAP.
I wrote some simple "sum" function in "Server.h" file.

```
//gsoap ns service name: Server
//gsoap ns service namespace: urn:Server
//gsoap ns service style: rpc
//gsoap ns service encoding: encoded

int ns__sum(int a, int b, int *res);
```

Then I generated "Server.h" using this command **soapcpp2 -i -s C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Server.h** and I got these files:

```
soapServerService.h
soapServerService.cpp
soapServerProxy.h
soapServerProxy.cpp
Server.nsmap
soapStub.h
soapH.h
soapC.cpp
```

Then I tried this code:

```
#include "Server.nsmap"
#include "soapServerService.h"

int main() 
{
    ServerService server();
    server.serve();

    return 0;   
}

int ServerService::sum(int a, int b, int *res)
{
    *res = a + b;
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

but I have some error like this:

> request for member 'serve' in 'server', which is of non-class type
>   'ServerService()

What does it mean and what I have to do?

Comment: does the function serve exist?

Comment: Yes. I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object of ServerService,create it as ServerService server. You are creating it as ServerService server()

Comment: The advice is correct, the reason not. (The used syntax does not create an object, but declares a function).

Comment: yeah,it is creating a function,the object server doesnt exist,which is being used to call serve. This appears to me as the reason too. May b the author can try that

Comment: Yes I undertand. Thanks, but when I declare ServerService server; here occured an error  "undefined reference to `ServerService::ServerService()'

Comment: Makes sense - when you only declare a function `ServerService server()`, the compiler doesn't yet check how that function will create its return value. But `ServerService server;` means " create an object using the default constructor". That default constructor should obviously exist for that to work. If there is no default constructor, only constructors that  needs arguments, you must provide them.

Comment: @MSalters is absolutely correct..!       
Author : what i meant is you must create an object,look into class declaration and construct an object to call the serve method,in the code you posted u werent doing that